# Building a query like a "dynamic pivot" with columns coming from another table rows

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, dynamic-programming

When i Having these tables:

```
Table  'hProduct':

Id      productName
--------------------  
1       Product A
2       Product B
3       Product C
4       Product D
5       Product E


Table 'hStores':

Id     StoreName
--------------------
1      Store A
2      Store B
3      Store C
4      Store D
...      ...

Table 'hHistory':

id     idStore      idProduct    lastUpdate            Value
-------------------------------------------------------------
1      1            1             2014-11-04 15:10:46   12.20
1      1            1             2014-11-05 15:10:46   12.25
2      2            1             2014-11-04 15:10:50   12.60
2      2            1             2014-11-05 15:10:50   12.63
3      3            1             2014-11-06 15:10:48   12.30
3      3            1             2014-11-05 15:10:48   12.33
4      4            1             2014-11-06 15:10:52   12.26
4      4            1             2014-11-06 15:10:52   12.28
...   ...          ...                    ...            ...
```

Is possible in MySql to Have This output?

```
Product       Store A     Store B     Store C     Store D   ...
------------------------------------------------------------------
Product A     12.25       12.63       12.33       12.28     ...
Product B      ...         ...         ...         ...      ...
```

I'm wanting to keep a catalog of some products on different stores and their values (listing it with last price updates from table 'hHistory' that have a register of values and dates, using MAX(lastUpdate) when lastUpdate is TimeStamp format ), which having on that output, Stores as columns coming from table 'hStores' (and having a dynamic variable number of columns based on how much rows 'hStores' has), and of course, having how much products on'hProducts' table could have.

I know this could is very hard and complex to put in code. I was trying to figure out how could create this for a weeks and could'nt imagine how to do that, and if this is really possible using pure MySql.

Any help or information on how to start and maybe a sample code to start working will be really appreciated!

Comment: But why would you want to do this?

Comment: is a pricing system that I am building to maintain competition in the business where I work, where I collect products, companies and their prices, with daily updates. This part is the general report

Comment: The really main reason to do that, in that way is to learn. I love challenges, and i hate do give it out without try everything.

Comment: Your general reports are read from a MySQL CLI?

Comment: On really, its a Recordset, i'm using ASP

Comment: So just return a well-ordered result set, and handle issues of data display in A$P - much more flexible and scalable

Comment: Its mean that there is no way to do it in MySQL ?

Comment: There is a way. It's just extremely tedious. It involves the construction of a stored procedure and a prepared statement, and offers no performance benefit over the alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to Clarify, i researched everywhere, and studying about dynamic mySql i was able to build my custom query without much trouble. But this was a little bit confusing on starting process.

If someone need something similar, i hope that solution could help.

The tables:

**Table 'hProduct':**

```
Id  productName             categoryId
--------------------------------------
1   Tablet XingLing 12GB    1
2   Celular XingLing 12GB   2
3   Tablet XingLing 2       1
6   Testes                  5
5   Tablet XingLing 3       3
8   Novo Produto            7
7   Produto de Testes       5
9   Galaxy s5 single black  8
```

**Table 'hStores':**

```
Id  StoreName
-----------------------
1   Store 1
2   Store 5
3   Store 3
4   Store 6
5   Store 8
6   Store 9
7   Store 2
8   Store 4
9   Store 10
10  Store 11
11  Store 12
12  Store 13
13  Store 14
14  Store 15
15  Store 16
16  Store 17
```

**Table 'hTarget':**

```
Id  Url     productId  storeId  categoryId  lastUpdate
----------------------------------------------------------
1   ...     1          1        1           2014-11-06 15:10:41
4   ...     1          7        1           2014-11-06 15:10:46
5   ...     2          1        1           2014-11-06 15:10:49
6   ...     3          1        1           2014-11-06 15:10:52
7   ...     3          7        1           2014-11-06 15:10:55
8   ...     1          4        1           2014-11-06 15:10:59
9   ...     7          1        5           2014-11-06 15:11:01
10  ...     8          1        7           2014-11-06 15:11:04
11  ...     9          5        8           2014-11-06 15:11:06
12  ...     9          14       8           2014-11-06 15:11:08
13  ...     1          14       1           2014-11-06 15:11:11
14  ...     1          5        1           2014-11-06 15:11:13
```

**Table 'hHistory':**

```
Id  idTarget    dateTime                valueInCash
---------------------------------------------------
1   1           2014-11-06 15:10:44     1179.9
2   4           2014-11-06 15:10:47     0
3   5           2014-11-06 15:10:51     109.79
4   6           2014-11-06 15:10:54     339.9
5   7           2014-11-06 15:10:58     1499
6   8           2014-11-06 15:10:59     399
7   9           2014-11-06 15:11:03     16.66
8   10          2014-11-06 15:11:05     487.81
9   11          2014-11-06 15:11:07     2399
10  12          2014-11-06 15:11:10     2399
11  13          2014-11-06 15:11:12     2111.12
12  14          2014-11-06 15:11:14     2111.12
```

**Table 'hCategoryStores':**

```
Id      categoryId  storeId
---------------------------
1       1           1
2       1           7
4       1           3
5       1           8
9       5           1
8       1           2
10      1           4
11      5           2
12      7           1
13      7           2
14      8           5
15      8           14
16      8           16
17      8           1
18      8           4
19      1           14
20      1           5
```

**Table 'hCategory':**

```
Id  categoryName    userId
--------------------------
1   Tablets         999
2   Celulares       999
6   Impressoras     999
5   Monitores       999
7   Teste           999
8   Smartphones     999
```

And the output was:

```
Id    productName             Store 1       Store 2     Store 3     Store 4     Store 5   Store 6   Store 7    Store 8
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Tablet XingLing 12GB      1179.90     0           NULL        NULL        NULL      399       2111.12    2111.12
5     Celular XingLing 12GB     109.79      NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL      NULL       NULL
6     Tablet XingLing 2         339.89      1499        NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL      NULL       NULL
9     Produto de Testes         16.65       NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL      NULL       NULL
10    Novo Produto              487.80      NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL      NULL       NULL
11    Galaxy s5 single black    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL      2399       2399
```

And the query itself:

```
/* To Avoid 1024 VARCHAR Local Limitation */
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 4096;

/* Build a string with all rows present at relation of hCategoryStores & hStores 
   and put it as Columns for future query use, where hCategoryStores is a 
   custom set from full hStores database */
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN hS.storeName = ''', hS.storeName,
                ''' THEN hH.valueInCash END) `', hS.storeName, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM hCategoryStores hCS 
  INNER JOIN hStores hS ON hS.id = hCS.storeId 
  WHERE categoryId = 1;

/* Build a main query using custom columns set on @sql with their rules where        
   hHistory is a timeline database with prices along time, hProduct is a full product 
   list database and hTarget contains the setup and relations of data about different 
   stores & their prices conditions */  
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT hT.id, hP.productName, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM hTarget hT 
                     LEFT JOIN hStores hS ON hS.id = hT.storeId 
                     INNER JOIN hCategoryStores hCS ON hS.id = hCS.storeId 
                     INNER JOIN hHistory hH ON hH.IdTarget = hT.id
                     INNER JOIN hProduct hP ON hP.id = hT.productId
                      GROUP BY hP.id');

/* Call the Query */
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

It's a little bit long, but thats it. Thanks to everyone that tried to help me.

If someone can comment over that data / query set, it will be very appreciated! i love to learn and help.